# Finding cross-disciplinary themes in course listings

Tags: classification, predictive-models, text-mining, recommender-system

I’m building a dataset of course listings and am looking for methods/ algorithms to reveal clusters, connections, cross-disciplinary themes and threads that could be found in different courses.

Example of how a dataset entry might look like:

```
Name: Introduction to Social and Biological Networks
Faculty: Julia Radcliffe
Description:This course explores the Internet as a central component of modern scientific data processing and computation. We will examine the architecture of the Internet and the models of computation and data with which it is compatible. Through readings and exercises, students will explore the trade-offs of these various models and gain an appreciation for successful Internet-oriented system design for modern, federated, data- and compute-intensive scientific research. Students will complete a team project to develop an Internet-based system for scientific data processing. Python will be used for examples.
Recommended Prep: A course in object-oriented programming (e.g. Computer Science 51) and familiarity with the Unix operating system or variants.
School:Faculty of Arts & Sciences 
Department:Applied Computation  
Subject:Applied Computation  
Course Component:Unknown  
Units:4  
Grading Basis:Letter Graded  
Course Level:Primarily for Graduate Students  
Final Assessment Category:Unknown  
General Education:None
```

My task is to find connections between different course listings which wasnt known before. I’m at the liberty of adding more information ( Number of students who have enrolled, Students who have taken this course) if that will help understanding better connections.

I know of techniques like TFIDF ( Term Frequency- Inverse Document Frequency), LSI ( Latent Semantic Indexing), LDA ( Latent Dirichlet Allocation), Wikipre ESA ( Explicit Semantic Analysis). 
Are there methods which could be more appropriate in this case? Is a combination of any two methods perhaps a better solution?